# Can't center li elements correct in Bootstrap (Alpha)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am building my menu as a left sidebar and there I want to center my content within a `col-md-3`. Because I'm using Bootstrap 4 I use the `text-xs-center` class. It is working fine with the h1 heading but the menu points are displayed a bit more to the right.

Image:

[image: enter imagedescription here]

This is my HTML:

```
<nav class="col-sm-3  ">
<div class="container-fluid">

    <h1 class="Logostyle text-xs-center">HelloLogo</h1>

    <div class="row">
        <ul class="text-xs-center" routerLinkActive="active ">
            <li class="text-xs-center list-inline"><a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item list-inline"><a class="nav-link text-xs-center " routerLink="/services">Services</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item list-inline"><a class="nav-link text-xs-center " routerLink="/journal">Journal</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: can you add more html please

Comment: Hi, there is not much more html at the moment

Comment: then you miss one `div`.

Comment: oops, now it should be correct, i didn't copy everything, sry

Comment: at the end there is also a </nav> but stackoverflow is not showing it, i don't know why

Comment: add five spacebar before it.

Comment: ok now it is complete

Comment: Do you have a solution?

Comment: not sure what you really want ? but will try

Comment: I want to center the li elements, but they are not completely centered, like the "HelloLogo" they are bit more at the right side

Comment: you can see it on the attached image

Comment: I din't see anything center at all. also not see col-md-3 you mention.

Comment: the image is just the extract. But you can clearly see, that the h1 is centered and that the points below are a bit more driven to the right side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that you want this one:

Because of you are using `.col`, `.container-fluid` then `h1` and then you `.row` and have `ul` inside.

`.row` has a little bit of margin and padding so your context box is a bit different from `h1` that is using `.container-fluid` box. (You can easy see how is the box be by add `div { border: red solid 3px; }` to see it.
) Also the `ul` have a browser user agent style by default it will be push to right with `-webkit-padding-start: 40px;`. So to prevent it move a bit to right, you can just easy remove `ul` and `li` then use `a` with style instead. I will provide it below.

```
<nav class="col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="Logostyle text-xs-center">HelloLogo</h1>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-12 text-xs-center">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/services">Services</a>
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/journal">Journal</a>
        </div>
    </div> 
</nav>
```

You also have to add this into your stylesheet

```
a.nav-link{
    display: block;
}
```

Result : [image]

Comment: No, I copied it and the outcome is wrong, see here http://imgur.com/a/EVDCd 
Now the h1 is not centered and the menu points aren't either

Comment: add description text.

Comment: Well I don't know why it is not working by me. I am using Bootstrap alpha 4, you too?

Comment: Ahh i solved it, if use your code and change the class text-center to text-xs-center then it's working fine. Pls add this to your solution, so I can give you a "like" for the right answer

Comment: Thx for your help! Awesome